# AdonisJS Associate with multiple oneToMany relationships

Tags: javascript, arrays, adonis.js, associate

How do I associate an array of values from a oneToMany relationship in Adonis.

The docs show the following to associate a single value

```
const Profile = use('App/Models/Profile')
const User = use('App/Models/User')

const user = await User.find(1)
const profile = await Profile.find(1)

await profile.user().associate(user)
```

What if my form had submitted an array of multiple user id's 
I know I could use array.map and loop over each one, but that is an asynchronous command and my controller would try to respond to the client before map had completed.

```
users.map(async (u)=>{
  let user = await User.find(u)
  await profile.user().associate(user)
})

return //I think this would return before the above map function completed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a for of

```
for (const u of users) {
    const user = await User.find(u)
    await profile.user().associate(user)
}
```